# Python Dictionary and functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with this code. The problem is that when I run it, it starts WITH the `def hellokitchen`, and I tried changing `hellokitchen()` from 'kitchen' in dictionary to `hellokitchen()` but prints function `hellokitchen` at 0xblahblahblah. I need this to work.
I have tried another way, but prints None

```
MAP = {'foyer_forward': 'hall',
   'foyer_right': 'bedroom',
   'foyer_back': 'front door',
   'foyer_left': 'office',
   'hall_back': 'foyer',
   'hall_left':'kitchen',
   'bedroom 2_back': 'hall',
   'bedroom_back': 'foyer',
   'bedroom_left': 'bathroom',
   'front door_back': 'foyer',
   'office_back': 'foyer',
   'kitchen_back': 'hall',
   'bathroom_back': 'bedroom'}

def hellokitchen():
guess = input("your plan works!")
if guess == 'sup':
    print("YOUR PLAN DEFINITELY WORKS")
return




DESC = {'foyer': 'You are in the foyer of the house',
    'hall': 'You are in the Hall. The place is completely ruined, and you despise the look of it. ',
    'bedroom': 'You are in the bedroom. The body of the victim is lying on the floor, drenched in blood. A pungent smell is radiating out of the corpse. There are two doors, one back to the foyer, and one leading to the bathroom on the left.',
    'front door': 'The front door is locked. You have to find the murderer to escape! Type back to return to the foyer.',
    'office': 'You walk into a room which looks like an Office. You scour the room for evidence but return nothing. Type back to return to the foyer.',
    'kitchen': hellokitchen(),
    'bathroom': 'You are in the bathroom'}


FINISH = 'SECRET_ROOM'
UNLOCKED_DOOR = 'kitchen'

name = input('\033[1;36;1m What is your name? > ')
print('Hello', name)
print("ENTER STARTING DESC.")

room = 'foyer'

while True:
print(DESC[room])
if room in FINISH:
    break

direction = input('Enter a direction. Choose from forward, back, left, right or quit >')
key = room + '_' + direction

if key in MAP:
    room = MAP[key]

else:
    print('You can\'t go ' + direction + '.')

print('Congratulations!')
```

Comment: it probably prints the memory block when you had `'kitchen': hellokitchen` in your dictionary and not `'kitchen': hellokitchen()`?

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Stop editing your post to say it's resolved. The content stays on the site, as you agreed to by posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in

```
print(DESC[room])
```

When you are in the kitchen you will have this:

```
print(hellokitchen)
```

which prints out the memory line as you have described above, as it telly python to print out the function object called `hellokitchen` and the representation of the function object looks like you have described above, something like:

```
<function hellokitchen at 0x0000000004351C18>
```

What you intended was, that python calls the function called `hellokitchen` which you can achieve by changing the `print(DESC[room])` to:

```
if callable(DESC[room]):    # you have a function in your dict
    DESC[room]()            # call that function
else:
    print(DESC[room])       # in case of string, just print it
```

This will check if you have saved a function in your dictionary (like for `'kitchen': hellokitchen`), or not (you have a string like `'bathroom': 'You are in the bathroom'` which can be printed directly)